# Apache Spark Scala - data analysis - error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to/still learning Apache Spark/Scala. I am trying to analyze a dataset and have loaded the dataset into Scala. However, when I try to perform a basic analysis such as max, min or average, I get an error -

```
error: value select is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]
```

Could anyone please shed some light on this please? I am running Spark on the cloudlab of an organization.

Code:

```
// Reading in the csv file

val df = sc.textFile("/user/Spark/PortbankRTD.csv").map(x => x.split(","))  

// Select Max of Age

df.select(max($"age")).show()
```

Error:

```
<console>:40: error: value select is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]                                                
          df.select(max($"age")).show()
```

Please let me know if you need any more information.
Thanks

Comment: To add to @thebluephantom's incredibly helpful comment, you should read about converting an RDD to a DataFrame.  `select` is a method on `DataFrame`; you're handing it an `RDD` (as the error message indicates).

Answer (score 3):

Following up on my comment, the `textFile` method returns an `RDD[String]`.  `select` is a method on `DataFrame`.  You will need to convert your `RDD[String]` into a `DataFrame`.  You can do this in a number of ways.  One example is

```
import spark.implicits._

val rdd = sc.textFile("/user/Spark/PortbankRTD.csv")
val df = rdd.toDF()
```

There are also built-in readers for many types of input files:

```
spark.read.csv("/user/Spark/PortbankRTD.csv")
```

returns a `DataFrame` immediately.

Comment: Thank so much  user4601931! Really appreciate the guidance. Will try this and revert.

Comment: No problem! If you think the answer addresses your question, you should click the checkmark to accept it.  This way the question doesn't pop up again in the feed.  This isn't definitive, and if a better answer comes along, you can accept that one instead.